# How to fix keras.backend.eval being really slow

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I want to evaluate the loss function of a model for each sample after training. Just calling loss results in a single value for each batch, so I call the loss function manually on the predict()ed value.

This requires a tensor evaluation, since the loss returns a tensor. Evaluating this tensor is easy enough, but the call takes forever, despite being a simple operation.

I've tried session.run from the keras session, as well as keras.backend.eval, both have the same issue. I've also tried upgrading keras, but it's already on 2.2.4

```
import keras
indim = 28
model = Sequential([Dense(8,input_shape=(indim,),activation='tanh'),Dense(4,activation='tanh'),Dense(1,activation='linear')])
model.compile(optimizer='adam',loss='mae')
def foo():
    for i in range(0,500):
        input = np.random.rand(32,28)
        Y     = np.random.rand(32,1)
        Ypred = model.predict(input)
        loss = model.loss_functions[0](Y,Ypred)
        loss = keras.backend.eval(loss)
```

```
%prun foo()
```

I expected the above example to finish in a fraction of a second. It takes 20 seconds at first, 40 seconds on the second run, with the profiler returning:

```
      500   27.580    0.055   27.580    0.055 {built-in method _pywrap_tensorflow_internal.ExtendSession}
      500   18.866    0.038   18.866    0.038 {built-in method _pywrap_tensorflow_internal.TF_SessionRun_wrapper}
    16500    0.124    0.000    0.129    0.000 pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py:39(_swig_setattr_nondynamic)
```

subsequent calls take longer and longer (20, 40, 80 seconds!)

Comment: Do you just want loss of each batch? What about `model.evaluate`?

Comment: I want a loss of each sample. Of course I could make 1-sized batches and evaluate them, but I thought that would be slower, and expected the .predict call to (in general) take longer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution ends up being the use of K.placeholder. Otherwise the global graph grows with every call to the model loss function.

```
import time

import numpy as np

import keras.backend as K
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.models import Sequential

indim = 28
model = Sequential([Dense(8, input_shape=(indim,), activation='tanh'), Dense(4, activation='tanh'),
                    Dense(1, activation='linear')])
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mae')
y_pred = K.placeholder([None, 1])
y_true = K.placeholder([None, 1])
loss_fn = model.loss_functions[0](y_true, y_pred)

for i in range(0, 500):
    s = time.time()
    input = np.random.rand(32, 28)
    Y = np.random.rand(32, 1)
    Ypred = model.predict(input)
    _ = K.get_session().run(loss_fn, feed_dict={y_true: Y, y_pred: Ypred})
    print("Took", time.time() - s)
```